# Launch an iTunes song from an URL

Tags: itunes

Is there a way, using a URL, to launch a particular track in the iTunes player (on the local machine)?

I've noticed that URLs starting with "itunes://" launch the iTunes application, but cause it to look up an item in the iTunes Store.

However, I am not interested in the iTunes Store;  I only want to the player to play a track in my local library.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows, but I was hoping that the answer to the question would be OS-agnostic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>I moved my iTunes library around a bit, so I don't know the canonical path. Just adjust the URLs you see in this answer.</sub>

Configure Firefox to handle `audio/mpeg` using iTunes:

[image]

Then, open a URL in Firefox such as (on Mac OS X):

```
file:///Users/username/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Music/Artist/Album/Title.mp3
```

and it will play in iTunes. Since it's already in the library, it's not added again.

Using a browser like Firefox (not IE) has the benefit of being able to browse the file system if you want, and clicking on a file then opens in iTunes.

[image]

---

Similarly, in OS X Terminal, you can use the following:

```
open -a iTunes file:///Users/username/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Music/Artist/Album/Title.mp3
```

It will use iTunes to open the URL, playing the file.

---

I don't have a Windows system with iTunes, it might work from Explorer if you use iTunes as default application for `.mp3` files.

Via [here](http://www.ericphelps.com/batch/rundll/), the following could work:

```
 rundll32.exe url.dll,FileProtocolHandler file://c:/wherever/iTunes/library/is/on/Windows/file.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

No. (Edit: After the comments below, I'm changing my answer to yes, you can. But not exactly the way I think you mean.)

The "itunes" function you mention is not intended to play music; it launches a web page inside the iTunes application.

To launch a local resource:

"The URL" of a track on your computer is the path to that song. A path looks like this:

```
C:\Users\goblinbox\Music\iTunes\iTunes Music\Bassnectar\Mesmerizing The Ultra
```

If you have iTunes set as your default music player, accessing the path to the song will launch iTunes and play the song.

You could, if you wanted, put that path into a web page, display it in a browser, and launch the song in iTunes on your local machine, but there's no advantage invoking web protocols when you already have access to the resource locally.

Comment: [Even Wikipedia disagrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

Comment: Well, sorta, yeah. Also: not exactly. - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url

Comment: It seems to be semantic, really, but if it's local, it's a path, and if it's hosted it's a URL or URI or something. The difference is the state of the box the resource is on. For instance, a path on my local machine is not universal, because you cannot reach it even if you know the full path. This is because my machine is a host, not a server, and not public. I think.

Comment: The U stands for Uniform, not Universal. If I'm in the same domain as a machine, `http://machinename/path/` works (instead of `http://machinename.bigcorp.com/path/`) and you would't argue it's not a URL there. File URLs are proper URLs.

Comment: All paths, regardless of protocol or the existence or not of a domain, are called URLs, then? Thanks! I didn't know that. (I thought certain protocols had to be involved else it was just a local path. Like in your example of a small domain you had to use http and a different naming convention.)

Comment: No. `/Users/danielbeck/Documents` is a path, but not a URL. So is `C:\Users\danielbeck\My Documents` or `..`. But if you have the general layout of a URL, it can be considered a URL. On Mac OS X, it's actually a popular way to handle shareware registration: Click a link with a custom protocol handler in an email, and the application pops up and thanks you. On iOS, it's how interprocess communication works: A program tell iOS to open a URL like `twitter://post/Hello%20World` and the associated twitter client opens up and handles it. (Although these use cases stretch the "resource" semantics)

Comment: It can't be just the general format; the difference has to be between locally accessible resources and resources that can only be accessed remotely via networking protocols. That you can invoke a network protocol to launch a local resource doesn't mean that you should, right? I can either drill down to a text file in my file structure and open it, or I can write an HTML document pointing to the file, launch a browser, and use http to read it. The first is a path, the second is a URL, they do they same thing, but they're not the same.

Comment: Your browser doesn't use HTTP to browse the file system. It just knows how to handle `file://` URLs: By translating to paths and invoking system APIs. For a browser, URLs are just the natural representation of file system locations instead of "real" paths. URLs are just a resource location representation, how to handle them is up to the implementer. Consider the `twitter://` URL scheme I mentioned: There's not even a real resource associated with it. And even more common URLs don't necessarily have anything to do with network resources, as `file://` scheme clearly shows.

Comment: The items before :// are protocols, not locations. They're a part of a URL. A URL is a string that contains both a protocol and a resource. Must be. Otherwise there's no difference between a URL and a path.

Comment: Yes! - http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/definition.html :-)